# Can you program python onto an Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

Im looking for a way to program using python on an Arduino. Are there any up-to date interpreters available? I looked at some older questions, but there are no up-to date versions. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to program it on an Arduino Uno rev 3.

Comment: Check out Micro-python. I used it on a ESP32 and it is great. I have a repository on how to install it: https://github.com/progamandoconro/ESP32-WROOM

Comment: why would you program an Arduino in Python? What's wrong with C++?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.adafruit.com/category/micropython

Comment: I need to use python for a neural network that i want to run on the arduino, and would rather not convert it to C++.

Comment: @Rodrigo The ESP32 works fine with MicroPython? Even though it's not on the list of compatible boards, it works fine?

Comment: @AndrewNelson, yes, the ESP32 works very well with MicroPython but I do not know if enough for Neural Network.  It is possible to install external modules in MicroPython (default modules are limited), but memory size could be an issue.

Comment: Do not expect to run tensorflow in micropython though. There is dedicated hardware for AI, maybe you want to look at nvidia jetson nano or the jevois camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot program an Arduino Uno in Python. You need a more powerful MCU to run a Python compiler/runtime like MicroPython.

MicroPythons memory requirements exceed Arduinos specs.